# How do you decompose color by using modulo operator in C?

Tags: c, graphics, colors, hex, bit-manipulation

Let's call color information in the hexadecimal form `int color_hex`

In C Language, I use a bitwise operator(>>) to decompose it to R(Red), G(Green), and B(Blue).

Red: `(color_hex >> 16) & 0xFF`

Green: `(color_hex >> 8) & 0xFF` 

Blue: `(color_hex >> 0) & 0xFF`

There is no problem with this, right?

I've recently seen someone else doing in the other way, which is:

Red: `(color_hex >> 16) % 256 / 255.0`

Green: `(color_hex >> 8) % 256 / 255.0`

Blue: `(color_hex >> 0) % 256 / 255.0`

I'm confused about the way it works.

1)What does a modulo operator do in here?

2)What about dividing it by 255.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods produce two different representations of colors. One represents the intensity of each color as an integer from 0 to 255 (inclusive). The other represents the intensity of each color as a floating-point number from 0 to 1 (inclusive).

As long as `x` is a non-negative integer, `x & 0xFF` is equivalent to `x % 256`. The `%` operator produces a remainder after division; `x % 256` is the remainder when `x` is divided by 256. `&` does a bitwise AND; `x & 0xFF` produces the low eight bits of `x`. Because all bits above the eighth bit represent powers of two that are 256 or more, taking just the low eight bits is equivalent to removing all multiples of 256, leaving just the remainder. This is why `x & 0xFF` and `x % 256` are equivalent for non-negative `x`. (For negative `x`, they differ due to how negative numbers are represented with bits and due to `%` producing a negative remainder.)

Since they are equivalent, a compiler should optimize them to the same code, if it knows the left operand is non-negative.

So both methods shown in the question are identical up to that point. The latter merely divides by `255.0` to scale the result from 0-255 to 0-1.